# Reference to "this" lost when using dojo aspect around a GridX tree

Tags: javascript, dojo, aspect, gridx

I am trying to use an around aspect for the `expand` function of a `GridX`'s tree.

The simplified code goes like:

```
var myGrid = ...; // features a tree
var myConditional = ...; // some boolean


dojo.aspect.around(myGrid.tree, "expand", function(original) {
    return function(id, skip) {
        // TODO check the conditional and decide whether 
        // to return the deferred function as is, or 
        // return a function that does nothing but log into the console
        var deferred = original(id, skip);
        return deferred;
    };
});
```

Unfortunately, the invocation of dojo aspect *as is* (i.e. without any check for my conditional, etc.) is problematic.

Once the expando is clicked, an error is thrown in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.isExpanded is not a function
```

... pointing at the body of the GridX tree module's `expand` original function:

```
var d = new Deferred(), t = this;
if(!t.isExpanded(id) && t.canExpand(id)){ // here
```

Clearly my interpretation of how aspect around works is mistaken, and the scope of `t` becomes the `Window` object instead of the tree itself.

I am hoping there's a quick fix/workaround I can use?

**Clarification on my actual purpose**

Under certain circumstances, the back-end queried by the store underlying the grid will be unreachable for a short amount of time. The way things are implemented, expanding on nodes of the tree will query the back-end. During the very short window while the back-end is unavailable (which I can easily know from the front-end code), I'd like to ignore clicks on the expandos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to bind tree instance to your function. Something like this:

```
var myGrid = ...; // features a tree
var myConditional = ...; // some boolean

const condExpand = function(id, skip) {
        var deferred = original(id, skip);
        return deferred;
    }.bind(myGrid )


dojo.aspect.around(myGrid.tree, "expand", function(original) {
    return condExpand
});
```

I'm not sure about where a particular context is lost in your case, but you can play with this to make it work for you.

**Update:**

Tried to reproduce situation. Below is working example:

```
    const testObject = {    
      isNumeric: function(number) {
        return typeof number === "number"
      },
      testMethod: function() {
        console.log('testMethod', this)
        console.log("Is 5 a number: ", this.isNumeric(5))
      }
    }

    const aroundFunc = function(originalTestmethod){
        return function(method, args){
          // doing something before the original call
          console.log("Before", this)

          //Here context still corect. 
          //So bind it to passed here original method:

          var deferred = originalTestmethod.bind(this)(method, args)


          // doing something after the original call
          console.log("After")
          return deferred;

        }
      }

require(['dojo/aspect'], function(aspect) {
   aspect.around(testObject, "testMethod", aroundFunc)  
   testObject.testMethod()  

})
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apologies for the delay, had a long code-less weekend. There was an answer similar to yours from another user (now deleted), but it didn't work, likely because the binding wasn't done on the right object. I'll take a look at yours as soon as I can, and see if that makes more sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be working either - same error. Note that you can't declare the `condExpand` separately as `original` would be unknown. However, even when I tried returning the function declared inline while binding it to either the grid or its tree, the issue still occurred.

Comment: I have modified my code to bind the deferred function to the tree, broadly following your example, and that worked: something in the lines of `var deferred = original.bind(self.myTable.tree)(id, skip);`. I think the issue was trying to bind the outer function instead of the deferred one.

Comment: Yes, context was lost particullary in this place `var deferred = ...`, but I think you should be able to bind deferred function right to `this` keyword: `original.bind(this)(id, skip)`. Anyway, if binding explicitly to instace works for you, it's ok too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I found a "solution" that seems absolutely barbaric, but works for me.

Hopefully someone has a better idea, possibly using dojo/aspect.

I've literally copypasted the `Tree.js` module's code into my own implementation, only adding my own condition:

```
myGrid.tree.expand = function(id, skipUpdateBody)  {
    var d = new dojo.Deferred(),
        t = this;
    // added my condition here
    if ((!t.isExpanded(id) && t.canExpand(id)) && (myCondition)) {
        // below code all original
        t._beginLoading(id);
        t.grid.view.logicExpand(id).then(function(){
            dojo.Deferred.when(t._updateBody(id, skipUpdateBody, true), function(){
                t._endLoading(id);
                d.callback();
                t.onExpand(id);
            });
        });
    }else{
        d.callback();
    }
    return d;
};
```